# ImageResizer - The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: asp.net, imageresizer

This line is throwing the error: `ImageBuilder.Current.Build(imgURL, imgURL, resizeImg);`

Any idea why?

```
public void setImgSize(string controlId, string filename)
{
    decimal currentWidth = 0;
    decimal currentHeight = 0;
    int maxFileWidth = 600;
    int maxFileHeight = 600;
    bool imageExists = false;
    string imgURL = "~/SODocs/" + SONum + "/" + filename;
    string imgPath = Server.MapPath(imgURL);
    if (File.Exists(imgPath))
    {
        imageExists = true;
        System.Drawing.Image imgFile = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(imgPath);
        Image imgControl = FindControl(controlId) as Image;
        int maxDisplayWidth = 273;
        int maxDisplayHeight = 200;
        currentWidth = Convert.ToDecimal(imgFile.Width);
        currentHeight = Convert.ToDecimal(imgFile.Height);
        int newDisplayWidth = 0;
        int newDisplayHeight = 0;
        int paddingHeight = 0;

        if (currentHeight > currentWidth)
        {
            imgControl.Height = maxDisplayHeight;
            newDisplayWidth = Convert.ToInt32((maxDisplayHeight / currentHeight) * currentWidth);
            imgControl.Width = newDisplayWidth;
            imgControl.Style.Add("margin", "0 auto");
        }
        else if (currentWidth > currentHeight)
        {
            newDisplayHeight = Convert.ToInt32((maxDisplayWidth / currentWidth) * currentHeight);

            if (newDisplayHeight > maxDisplayHeight)
            {
                // set newWidth based on maxHeight
                newDisplayWidth = Convert.ToInt32((maxDisplayHeight / currentHeight) * currentWidth);
                imgControl.Width = newDisplayWidth;
                imgControl.Style.Add("margin", "0 auto");
            }
            else
            {
                imgControl.Width = maxDisplayWidth;
            }

            paddingHeight = maxDisplayHeight - newDisplayHeight;
            imgControl.Style.Add("padding-top", paddingHeight.ToString() + "px");
        }

        imgControl.ImageUrl = imgURL;
        imgFile.Dispose();
        imgFile = null;

        if (imageExists)
        {
            // resize the image file
            if (currentWidth > maxFileWidth | currentHeight > maxFileHeight)
            {
                var resizeImg = new ResizeSettings();
                resizeImg.MaxWidth = maxFileWidth;
                resizeImg.MaxHeight = maxFileHeight;

                ImageBuilder.Current.Build(imgURL, imgURL, resizeImg);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Silly question maybe, but do you have the image open in Photoshop or something similar?  I've also known that sort of error when I ftp a file to a server and the upload "hangs"

Comment: Hmmm... seems like something of the sort. I didn't have it blatantly open, though. Maybe something was holding onto it in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### You're opening the file for reading separately yourself, but expecting ImageResizer to be able to write to it later. System.Drawing does not handle file locking properly, and .Dispose() is not sufficient to deal with memory leaks nor the file access issue you're experiencing.

I suggest reviewing [the best practicies guide](http://imageresizing.net/docs/best-practices) for using ImageResizer.

What you're trying to accomplish here is likely achievable with the [URL API in a much simpler and less crash-prone manner](http://imageresizing.net/docs/basics).